# Request/Response filters in gatling

Tags: gatling

If I understood correctly gatling uses the ning:async-http-client library under the hood.
Is it possible to add request/response filters to the AsyncHttpClientConfig?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, no.

If you want to discuss feature requests, please use our [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gatling) and explain your use case.